# I cannot select anything (Blender 2.8)

Tags: animation

I am animating in blender 2.8 and I am in edit mode my cursor is a small white crosshair and i cant select anything, Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks, Cozmo [image: Cursor wont show but this is the image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going into local view (toggles on and off with the " / " button. It will confirm you're trying to select edges in the right object that way. Next, choose any of the three "select" options by pressing the top left button on the side-bar (arrow and crosshair). Try editing the object in the "Layout" tab at the very top of the screen. Last thing would be to confirm the option for "outline selected" is checked in the overlays menu (attached picture). Good luck[image]